# Should I scale my dataset before applyting VAR?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, feature-scaling, scale-invariance

I need to implement a VAR (vector autoregressive) model using a dataset of multiple financial indices.
The dataset is unscaled.
Should I scale it first or the VAR is not sensitive to scaling?
In case I have to scale it, if I run prediction I end up with a scaled value which might be hard to interpret (it will be centered). How to bring it back to the original scale?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to scale data before running a VAR model if you are going to estimate it using OLS; the same argument as for linear regression applies. (Related threads can be found on Cross Validated.)

On the other hand, if you are going to estimate the VAR model using, say, $L_2$ penalty (ridge), then you have to think about scaling, just as you have to think about scaling in linear regression estimated with $L_2$ penalty (ridge). (Again, related threads can be found on Cross Validated.)